# Error while initializing Service Account key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to initialize my service account key like so:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

// Initialize the Firebase Storage admin constant
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<DATABASE-NAME>.appspot.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE-NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

I get the following error `Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './serviceAccountKey.json'`

My serviceAccountKey.json file is inside my project name folder.

Also my dependencies from Firebase are the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "8.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0"
  },
```

My directory structure is the following:

```
-server
   -idea
   -bin
   -functions
   -node_modules
   -public
   -routes
   -views
   -.firebaserc
   -.gitignore
   - app.js
   - firebase.json
   - master
   - package.json
   - package-lock.json
   - serviceAccountKey.json ===> ***
   - server.iml
```

Why am I getting this error?

**Note: I've done some research on this and my file path does conform with the node.js documentation on using the require method.**

Comment: Please edit the question to show the directory structure of your project. The error message is essentially telling you there's no serviceAccountKey.json file in your functions folder.

Comment: By the way, if you don't need that specific service account, you can accept the default service account by calling `initailizeApp()` with no arguments.  That works for most basic cases.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my question. Also I need this initialization, since my signedUrl are being invalidated, I've submitted a ticket to Firebase, and Ian told me that I had to put my service account key to initialize the admin variable.

Comment: @andrea like @doug-stevenson said, it seems that your `serviceAccountKey.json` is in the wrong place. Can you share your repository if it's public? Maybe I can take a quick look. 

**NOTE:** Be careful with your service account file. You don't want this file in your repository especially if it's a public repo. I suggest using environment variables.

Comment: @ajorquera I can't share the repository since the project is for a client :( ... however the file structure is annotated previously

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help like this. Can you show the structure of the functions directory? Also, whats the name of the file where the serviceAccount is required and where is located? @Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Put your serverAccountKey.json file in your "functions" folder.  The entire contents of that gets packaged up and sent to Cloud Functions (unless you changed that default in firebase.json).  Files that are outside that folder will not be available.  Right now, it looks like the file is in "server".

Comment: still getting: `Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './serviceAccountKey.json'`